# CSS Horizontal Drop Down Menu Positioning

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I've created a drop down menu using css where the drop down appears as a horizontal row instead of a vertical list. My only problem is that the drop down menu does not line up with the rest of menu. I want it to be flush with the left side of the navigation bar.

The page is up at this address: http://concept82.com/CBHweb/index2.html

The code for my drop down menu is:

```
#navholder{
background-color: #594361;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 868px;
height: 25px;
font-family: P22, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
#nav {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#nav li {
   list-style: none;
   float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    width: 140px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
   color: #201E30;
}
#nav li ul {
   display: none;
}
#nav li ul a{
    width: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.hover ul {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   display: inline;
   padding-top: 5px;
}
#nav li:hover li, #nav li.hover li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #594361;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-right: 1px solid #594361;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
 #nav li.first, #nav li.hover li.first {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #594361;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-left: 1px solid #594361;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
#nav li:hover li a, #nav li.hover li a {
   color: #201E30;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   }
#nav li li a:hover {
   color: #201E30;
   }
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: the left:0 should be whatever your margin is. this is most likely causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change position of **#navholder** as relative.

```
#navholder{
position: relative;
background-color: #594361;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 868px;
height: 25px;
font-family: P22, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured it was something simple like that. I'm still learning all.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the ul when hovering on the list you specify left as 0 px, aligining it to the left of the page, change it to your margin width then it will be in the right place

```
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```